# How to set up a qasync event loop in another thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5, python-asyncio

I am developing an asynchronous PyQt application - meaning, I need both `asyncio` and PyQt. Since both `asyncio` and PyQt use their own event loops, this would be impossible without `qasync`, which is created to solve this problem. Here is how you use it:

```py
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
asyncio.set_event_loop(qasync.QEventLoop(app))
exit(app.exec_())
```

Now, I want to move all my logic into a separate "worker" thread. To do this, I create a `QThread`, which automatically sets up a new Qt event loop for this thread. But I need to be able to use `asyncio` in that thread, too, so I have to do the same `qasync` trick for the worker thread.

But how do I do it? To my understanding, `qasync.QEventLoop(app)` would get the application's main event loop, not the thread's loop. And you can't do `qasync.QEventLoop(thread)`.

Here is a code example.

```py
import logging
import sys
import datetime
import asyncio
import qasync

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot, QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QWidget, QVBoxLayout


class Logic(QObject):  # Logic to run in a separate thread
    enabled = False

    @pyqtSlot()
    def start(self):
        logger.debug('Start called')
        self.enabled = True
        asyncio.create_task(self.process())

    @pyqtSlot()
    def stop(self):
        logger.debug('Stop called')
        self.enabled = False

    async def process(self):
        while self.enabled:
            logger.debug(f'Processing ({datetime.datetime.now()})...')
            await asyncio.sleep(0.5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s:%(name)s: %(message)s')
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    asyncio.set_event_loop(qasync.QEventLoop(app))

    logic = Logic()

    # Move logic to another thread
    # thread = QThread()
    # logic.moveToThread(thread)
    # thread.start()

    window = QMainWindow()
    window.setCentralWidget(QWidget())
    window.centralWidget().setLayout(QVBoxLayout())

    window.centralWidget().layout().addWidget(QPushButton(text='Start', clicked=logic.start))
    window.centralWidget().layout().addWidget(QPushButton(text='Stop', clicked=logic.stop))

    window.show()

    logger.debug('Launching the application...')
    exit(app.exec_())
```

If you run it as it is, it works - in a single thread. But if you uncomment the "`Move logic to another thread`" block, then it fails, because there is `RuntimeError: no running event loop` for `asyncio.create_task()`.

How do I fix this? I guess the desired behavior is obvious - it should behave the same as it did with a single thread, except everything inside `logic` should run in a separate thread.

A sub-question is, what exactly does `qasync` do? Is my understanding correct that it somehow allows to use the same main Qt event loop for `asyncio`? So `qasync.QEventLoop(app)` returns a... some kind of `asyncio`-compatible proxy object to the existing Qt event loop?..

Comment: Your question is unclear, could you give a real example([mre]) where we can give you a precise solution.

Comment: @eyllanesc I have improved the question. Is this good enough?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is due to that you are setting `QEventLoop` created from the `QApplication` (which is in main thread). Here is my version to show how to run `asyncio` from a separate thread:

```
import logging
import sys
import datetime
import asyncio
import qasync
import threading
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot, QThread, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QWidget, QVBoxLayout


class Logic(QObject):  # Logic to run in a separate thread
    enabled = False

    @pyqtSlot()
    def start(self):
        logger.debug('Start called')
        self.enabled = True
        asyncio.create_task(self.process())

    @pyqtSlot()
    def stop(self):
        logger.debug('Stop called')
        self.enabled = False

    async def process(self):
        while self.enabled:
            # demonstrate that we can emit a signal from a thread
            self.message.emit(f'Processing ({datetime.datetime.now()}), worker thread id: {threading.get_ident()}...')
            await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

    # signal declaration
    message = pyqtSignal(str)

# subclass QThread. override the run function to create an event loop and run forever
class WorkerThread(QThread):
    def run(self):
        loop = qasync.QEventLoop(self)
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        loop.run_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s:%(name)s: %(message)s')
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    logger.debug(f'main thread id: {threading.get_ident()}')

    # Move logic to another thread
    logic = Logic()    
    thread = WorkerThread()
    logic.moveToThread(thread)
    thread.start()

    window = QMainWindow()
    window.setCentralWidget(QWidget())
    window.centralWidget().setLayout(QVBoxLayout())

    window.centralWidget().layout().addWidget(QPushButton(text='Start', clicked=logic.start))
    window.centralWidget().layout().addWidget(QPushButton(text='Stop', clicked=logic.stop))
    # connect logic in workerThread to lambda function in this thread
    logic.message.connect(lambda msg: logger.debug(f'current thread: {threading.get_ident()}, {msg}'))

    window.show()

    logger.debug('Launching the application...')
    exit(app.exec_())
```